# Stubs package in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I need to typeset a flyer with tabs to tear-off. I found out the `stubs` package comes in handy, but it does not seem to work properly on the `beamer` class. Actually, it does something since the footline is removed by using the stubs command, but it seems that tabs are added at the bottom of a verical A4 paper, while I need them on the bottom of a `beamer` default format document.
Is there any possibility to do so?

My source is the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{stubs}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Header}
    Main body text.
  \end{frame}

  \stubs[15]{3cm}[more information]{Name \\ Mobile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stubs` package works just fine with beamer. It places the stubs in the background of the page and if the background colour of the frame is changed from white to transparent you can see them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{stubs}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Header}
    Main body text.
      \stubs[15]{3cm}[more information]{Name \\ Mobile}
  \end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]

However for more fine control I suggest to modify the footline instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

%\usepackage{stubs}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \quad
    \foreach \x in {1,...,22}{
        \rule{0.7pt}{1.5cm}\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.5cm}{some text\\some text}}
    }
    \rule{0.7pt}{1.5cm}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Header}
    Main body text.
  \end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, definetly an helpful answer. What about the horizontal size of the boxes? I tryied to tune the argument of the `\parbox` command, but the tabs do not enlarge whatsoever. The other parameters are ok however.

Comment: @MatteoZambra If you want to determine the horizontal size (which corersponds to the height of the rotated boxes) you could use a minipage instead of the parbox, this allows you to specify both the width and height